# Amazon SMS: How do I identify the sender from a message ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon's Small Email Service in a few web sites, and have just received an email from Amazon saying that they have identified TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 connections to AWS APIs from my account that must be updated to maintain AWS connectivity.

I started looking through my code, but as far as I can see, all sites use TLS1.2. I really need to find out which site(s) are sending using older versions, but can't see how to find this information.

Their email included some examples of connections, but I can't see any way of working out which site was responsible for sending. The list shows the region (which I know, as I only use one), the event (all sending a message) the message ID, source IP (all the same as all the sites live on the same server) and TLS version.

So, the only bit of information in there that could be of any use is the message ID, but I can't find any way of working out who the sender was. The AWS web site isn't any help, as it only seems to show overall statistics, no way (as far as I can see) of digging down and seeing individual messages.

I'm on the free tier, so can't contact support. Anyone any ideas how I identify which web site sent the emails?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: Nope, any ideas?